# Why do different browsers render the same HTML differently?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, rendering, mozilla

This is an html page :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Frame Set
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="frame.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winSize = $(window).width();
    var margin = (winSize-1000)/2;;
    $('#main').css({'margin-left':margin,'margin-right':margin});  
    }
)
$(function() {
  $(".frame").each(function() {
     var width = ($(this).find('.h').width()), 
         height = $(this).find('.l').height(),
         pad = $(this).find('.h').position().left,
         actWidth = width + 10,
         nHeight = height - (height * 2),
         rLeftMargin = actWidth - 1,
         bWidth = actWidth;

    $(this).find('.r').css({'margin-top':nHeight, 'margin-left':rLeftMargin, 'height':height});
    $(this).find('.h').css({'height':25});
    $(this).find('.b').css({'width':bWidth, 'margin-top':0});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" align="center" style="width:1000px; height:100%; text-align:left;">
    <div id="inner1" style="width:100%; height:20%; float:top; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div id="inner11">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="h" style="width:100%">Header</div>
                <div class="l" style="height:93%"></div>
                <div class="r"></div>
                <div class="b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner2" style="width:100%; height:60%;">
        <div id="inner21" style="width:69%; float:left; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px;">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="h" style="width:100%">Left Frame</div>
                <div class="l" style="height:93%"></div>
                <div class="r"></div>
                <div class="b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="inner22" style="width:29%; float:right; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px;">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="h" style="width:100%">Right Frame</div>
                <div class="l" style="height:93%"></div>
                <div class="r"></div>
                <div class="b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner3" style="width:100%; height:20%; float:bottom; margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
        <div id="inner23">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="h" style="width:100%">Footer</div>
                <div class="l" style="height:93%"></div>
                <div class="r"></div>
                <div class="b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Mozilla output :

[image]

This is IE8 output :

[image]

What is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Web Development

Comment: IE! IE! IE Ftagn!

Comment: Sigh... it's render, not output. And stop it with the punctuations already.

Comment: @Pekka - welcome to the world of IE won't die :)

Comment: Yeap. Welcome to my world Sarang. You should really have taken the blue pill.

Comment: Thanks all for bright welcome !!! But, is it world of IE or Mozzilla ~~~

Comment: Wait till you test on IE6!

Comment: You probably mean "Why IE does not display like the other browsers?"
Well, this is a long debate that would not qualify as a SO answer since it won't be [only] technical...

Comment: @Sarang - I've made some improvements to the spelling and grammar in your question. I see I was the 4th person to do this. Any particular reason that you are persisting in rolling back these corrections? Just to point out the bit in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) *If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*

Comment: @Sarang - I see that you've rolled my changes back. Just curious why?

Comment: Sarang: Oh, they render it perfectly, all right. It's just that each of them has a different idea of perfection.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

### How to fix this page

Let's help you out here a bit...

#### Use a Doctype

See @Topera's answer

#### To make everything center aligned

Please do not use

```
var winSize = $(window).width();
var margin = (winSize-1000)/2;;
  $('#main').css({'margin-left':margin,'margin-right':margin});  
}
```

Instead, use the CSS property `margin: 0 auto`. As a rule of thumb, always use a CSS solution instead of a Javascript where possible.

#### To create equal height columns

See:
http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

#### Use the correct terminology and better class name

To avoid confusion, please do not refer to non-frame elements as frames. For more about what frames are, see: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-frames-windows

Give your classes meaningful names. The reason for this is the same for any other language - so that when you come back later three month later you won't be scratching your head at classes named `l`, `r` and `h`.

#### Use semantically valid HTML

The `align` and `text-align` attributes are officially deprecated; please see the above solution on making things center aligned and the CSS property `text-align` property instead.

HTML elements give meaning to the content they are wrapped in. The headers you have for each 'frame' should be marked up with `<h2>` or `<h3>` headings instead - while `div`s are generic block level elements with no meaning, the `h1` to `h6` set of elements (for want of a better word) tells the browser that the text contained in them are headings.

#### CSS Box Model

Please have a look at how the box model and floats work in CSS. `bottom` and `top` are not valid values for the CSS `float` property.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/30-the-css-layout-model-boxes-border/#cssboxmodels
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

#### The Real Problem Here

is not with the browsers. IE8 surprisingly misbehaves much less than its predecessors. Try writing better HTML and CSS instead.

Answer (score 25):

You miss the tag `<!DOCTYPE>`, in the first line of page.

Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

If you don't put it, IE will activate `quirks mode`, and very strange things will happen.
When a browser activate quirks mode, many things change, as [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

NOTE: many browsers has quirks mode, not only IE (I know that firefox has too).

---

More about [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

List of [doctypes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp).

Comment: I have used strict,loose as well as trasitional.

Comment: @Sarang: Doctype makes the browser render the page as accurately as it can as that type of document. If it makes things "small", that's because they're written as small things.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that not all browsers use the same rendering engine or rendering rules.  This is a constant source of grief for web developers, and it's not something that seems to be going away anytime soon.

Make use of CSS whenever possible, as browsers tend to comply best when under strict stylesheet rules.  Beyond that, good luck and welcome to web dev :)

Answer (score 6):

1. use a doctype: [list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) at the
   moment i would use -> XHTML 1.0
   Strict, XHTML 1.1, HTML5 (do not if
   you are not familier with the
   problems that could occur
2. use a reset: [eric meyers reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) for xample is a good one
3. use a clearfix (and know when to use it) for example [the new clearfix](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) by Jeff Starr

using this three things, its a good start to let your website look the same in all browsers.
after that you must learn about custom browser bugs, like [double margin bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html) and so on.

Comment: +1 for mentioning using a reset - you don't know if you're dealing with browser quirks until the playing field is level.

Answer (score 2):

To be cross browser you need several tools, a lot of experience, and, in case of IE, a lot of luck.
In addition to the other answers here, you can use Yahoo CSS which give you a common base (all browsers don't have the same default values):
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/